# Apex & VF Code of Send Quote as E-Mail

Tags: visualforce, email, pdf, quote

I'd like to send my own Quote-PDF as E-Mail and not use the useless Salesforce Quote-PDF function. Problem is, using my own templates I can no longer use the native send Quote per E-Mail button. My question is if there is an override to this, so I can continue to the page and simply attach my own document. Perhaps with JavaScript?

In my fear that this isn't possible, anyone have the VF & Controller Code of the page, so I don't need to write the entire thing myself? I want to have the same page and everything but simply use my Conga Composer PDFs.

I'd be very glad to hear your responses!

Comment: Call Conga from a custom button. Check their docs or support.

Answer (score 2):

What I did once was remove the buttons on the Quote Page Layout for viewing/emailing the PDF and replace them with my own custom buttons. I ended up having a VF page that the button would go to that displayed the PDF (in an iframe) and let the user save or email the PDF via buttons on that page.

Hopefully the information isn't outdated, I posted about it a while back: http://michaelwelburn.com/2013/03/18/sending-visualforce-pages-as-email-attachments-in-salesforce/

Answer (score 2):

When you already have PDF page it is rely simple to create custom functionality for sending e-mails.
You just have to create custom button that will call VF page. In this page controller you should implement just pimple method that will create email with body basing on some html template and add PDF as attachment thanks to thePage.getContentAsPDF() and replace standart functionality.