# Can I Use Quote 'Create PDF' Button Programmatically?

Tags: pdf, quote

I recently have a client that wants the Email Quote functionality. However, in order to use that functionality, I need to create a Quote PDF.

I know I can create my own PDF, generate an attachment, then send it out as an e-mail. However, I would like to at least try using Salesforce's Quote PDF functionality to maintain consistency and above all else, having me write two templates.

TL;DR
Is it possible to programmatically use Salesforce's Quote PDF functionality? If not, is there a way to at least generate a PDF that will be in the Quote PDF related list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either create an addition custom button for another custom PDF quote template as you've suggested or a custom button code to attach the existing template to an email. See [Apex & VF Code of Send Quote as E-Mail](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13432/apex-vf-code-of-send-quote-as-e-mail?rq=1) for more.

Comment: I did find a hack to create the Quote PDF from the standard template. This is a relief, since I don't have to go custom (for the template at least) anymore. You can see the solution here: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/68243/can-you-use-a-pdf-template-in-apex/68300#68300

Comment: I should probably have mentioned that there's an unmanaged package available from the App Exchange called Simple Quotes and Invoices that provides all of what you need to do what was in the the post you just linked to. You simply need to adjust the templates to suit your requirements and can of course modify the controller as well for custom quote requirements. As that didn't seem relevant to you question, I didn't mention it.

Answer (score 0):

I found related answer here..helped me...
[Quote PDF, send in email, save in salesforce](https://salesforcetrail.blogspot.com/2016/12/how-to-save-quote-pdf-send-pdf-preview.html)